# How to handle multiple filtering params in JpaRepository

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a JpaRepository being exposed as Rest resource with `@RepositoryRestResource`:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>{
  //some methods
}
```

Now I want to handle another query operation with multiple filtering params (say 10). I can add a method like:

```
@Query("very long query...")
List<User> getFiltered(@Param("param1") String param1, @Param("param2") String param2...and so on);
```

but I don't like it and it would be hard to write the HQL query in the annotation. so I'm trying to find out any alternative. I don't want to handle requests with controllers, but just with rest resource repositories.

Answer (score 0):

In [Spring Data JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) in point 5.3.6. using named parameters said:

> Example 53. Using named parameters
>   public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository {
>
> @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or
>   u.lastname = :lastname")   User
>   findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
>                                    @Param("firstname") String firstname); 
>   }

With this method you can add multiples parameters changing or by And.

I hope help you. Best regards.